# template and <h:outputScript>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JavaScript file stored in the web root like,

```
SocialNetworking/web/resources/js/decimal_number_text_field.js
```

I'm trying to import this js file in an XHTML page like,

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/Template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">

            <h:outputScript name="../resources/js/decimal_number_text_field.js"/>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

The path is correct but it doesn't work.

---

The generated JavaScript tag looks like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SocialNetworking/javax.faces.resource/../resources/js/decimal_number_text_field.js.jsf">
</script>
```

So, the `src` attribute contains a wrong URL. If this script is added to the template within the `<h:head>` tag like so,

```
<h:outputScript name="js/decimal_number_text_field.js"/>
```

then it works fine.

Why does it take a wrong URL when this tag is placed in an XHTML page which covers the template?

Comment: Requires only `<h:outputScript name="js/decimal_number_text_field.js"/>` that generates this URL - `/SocialNetworking/javax.faces.resource/js/decimal_number_text_field.js.jsf`. This works fine, sorry.

Comment: I was writing you an answer. Do you understand what is going on or do you still want me to explain

Comment: Not sufficiently. Please add the answer :).

Comment: I will see you tomorrow. It is about 2 AM.

Comment: Sorry if I took so long to answer. I just knew this was answered already in SO. I just couldn't find it. So check the link below.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use : `#{request.contextPath}` as below. Based one your file path, `resources` package must be under web application root directory.

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/js/decimal_number_text_field.js.jsf">
</script>
```

directory structure :

```
applicaiton.war
     - resources
       - js
         - decimal_number_text_field.js.jsf
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give -1. I have now rearranged JavaScript files, CSS files and image files in the form of a library so that they can be accessed like `<h:outputScript library="default" name="js/decimal_number_text_field.js"/>`. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/1391249) answer. Thank you.